# Rotate a Scaled Image From the Center

Tags: android, andengine

I have some sprites (Well, custom classes that implement `Sprite`, but whatever) that I resize. AndEngine resizes the image from the center, which makes an image placed at 0,0 no longer appear at 0,0. To fix this I applied

```
    sprite.setScaleCenterX(0);
    sprite.setScaleCenterY(0);
```

This places the image where I want it. However, now when I rotate the image, the image moves around (If the image were a plain square, rotating it should make no visible change). To fix this I applied

```
    sprite.setRotationCenterX((sprite.getWidth() * sprite.getScaleX()) / 2);
    sprite.setRotationCenterY((sprite.getHeight() * sprite.getScaleY()) / 2);
```

(For some reason, resizing a `Sprite` doesn't change the dimensions of the sprite, just the visual image, hence multiplying it by the scale). This, however, did not correct the problem, but merely changed where the image moved to when flipped.

Is my math off here? Wouldn't this center the rotation on the image so that the image doesn't move position? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Below is full code:

```
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(0, 0, singleTrackTR, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    sprite.setScale(scaleX, scaleY);
    sprite.setScaleCenterX(0);
    sprite.setScaleCenterY(0);
    sprite.setRotationCenterX((sprite.getWidth() * sprite.getScaleX()) / 2);
    sprite.setRotationCenterY((sprite.getHeight() * sprite.getScaleY()) / 2);
```

Comment: This is not about your real question. getWidth() value doesn't change when you scale, that's why the getWidthScaled() exists. But it do the same with your code.(getWidth * getScaleX).

Comment: If possible, maybe you can try AnchorCenter branch. If I have a circle   sprite, when I rotate and scale at the same time, the center of circle doesn't move.

Comment: In your sprite, does it contain transparent part? If it do contain, does your visible part locate at the center of your image file?

Comment: @正宗白布鞋 Except it's not the center I want it anchored, hence why I have the `sprite.setScaleCenterX(0);`. And yes, it does have a transparent part, and yes, it's at the center of the file.

Comment: I have no idea why, but when I switched to using getWidthScaled(), it works!

Answer (score 0):

All your code is correct. I tried it myself, both the setProperty(x, y) and the setPropertyX/Y(a) versions.

By any chance, do you have it connected to a Body? Note that the Body also doesn't scale with a Sprite's setScale. It has its own setTransform method, which takes x and y (that you both have to divide by PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT) and a rotation value.

Comment: Body? I don't think so. It's just a sprite attached to the scene.